# Zipping a .txt file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, quazip

I have a simple application in Qt where the user enters data in a text file, which is then saved on desktop. After that I would like to be able to insert the .txt file in a .zip file.

I have tried to use QuaZIP with no success, it seems too complicated to understand.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just call a zipping utility (like "zip" & "unzip") using system commands. And make them a dependency of your code.

Comment: @111111 Which works perfectly cross-platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugless archive library is pretty good.This is how you would add files to an archive.

```
bool addFilesToArchive(const QString& archiveName, const QStringList& fileNames, const QString& password )
{
    Archive a;
    a.setArchiveName( archiveName );

    if ( !password.isEmpty() )
    {
        a.setPassword( password );
    }

    return a.addFiles( fileNames );
}
```

For more checkout the library at http://www.bugless.co.uk/products/archive/archive.html

Comment: The library has dual licensing (GNU GPL plus the Bugless proprietary
license).I remember it working when i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

libkarchive from the KDE frameworks provides exactly this. It's not released as a standalone library yet, though, but you could grab it from kdelibs git, branch frameworks.

Alternatively, the bugless library is an option as well, indeed.